# Navigation bar for Google won't fit across the width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to re-create the **www.google.com** page to learn css but I can't get the navigation bar to stretch across the page even though I have tried using `width:100%`. and `margin:0`on the ul element and the body element (it had no effect on the body element so I removed it from there)

I have also tried using

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
```

in my `#header` id but that didn't work either.

You can see in the image below that the navigation bar doesn't span across the entire width of the page. If you can't view the image properly, you can view the image through the link shown below.

I am sure it has something to do with the way I have positioned my elements because when I hover over my profile picture or the settings icon, it doesn't fit across the width of the block and goes out of the bar.

You can view the page online using the link below.

> [My Google Page](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/nidafarooqui/google-homepage/blob/master/google.html)

[image: The navigation bar]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.google-search {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#logo {
  width: 272px;
  height: 92px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.search {
  width: 535px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat right 4px center;
  background-size: auto 22px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  /*Styles */
  border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-right: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-left: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  /*Styles */
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}
button:hover {
  color: #222;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#lucky-button {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
a:hover {
  color: #222;
  background-color: #666666;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#header {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
#navbar {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#me {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#footer {
  bottom: -150px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 30px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}
#terms {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
/*font color for the footer links */

.link:link,
.link:visited {
  color: #777;
}
.link:hover {
  color: #777;
  text-decoration: underline;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
  <title>Google</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Google+</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Maps</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Play</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">YouTube</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drive</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="me">
        <li><a href="#">Nida Farooqui</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">0</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Share...</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0HkjOqmEXu8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/FQ22oIY4KjM/s24-c-mo/photo.jpg" width="24px" height="24px" alt="Nida Farooqui">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fez/512/FEZ-04-512.png" width="20px" height="20px">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="google-search">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="logo">

    <form>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search Google or type URL" name="search" class="search">
    </form>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Google Search</button>
      <button id="lucky-button">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Advertising</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Business</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="terms">
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Privacy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Terms</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Use Google.com</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The CSS below only shows the code related to the header and footer.

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;

}

a:hover {
    color: #222;
    background-color: #666666;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;

}

 #header {
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
 }

 #navbar {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;


 }

#me {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}



#footer {
    bottom: -150px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height: 30px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}



#terms {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

}


/*font color for the footer links */
.link:link, .link:visited {

    color: #777;
}


.link:hover {
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

EDIT: I have edited my code like you've all said but if you click on this link

> [My Google Page](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/nidafarooqui/google-homepage/blob/master/google.html)

you'll see it is still the same.

Comment: Removing the margin on the body, as pretty much all your answers tell you, fixes the issue.

Comment: This is suppose to work - remove margin ... also, your header css you need to specify the position because that top and left property wont do anything – Torean just now   edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw something that caused your `margin:0` property not to work.

In the CSS, remove the styling you did on the:

```
 #navbar {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
 }
```

//delete this above from the css then add the following to the body

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

JSFiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/6kwshsmo/

Comment: I did what you said but the navigation bar still looks the same on my chrome browser.

Comment: have you had a look at the link i sent? the fiddle shows it working and i am using chrome to test things and it seems to get the job done my side

Comment: no you were right, actually everyone was right, but I had to delete the navbar styling. My page was clashing with another css file.

Comment: Glad to help man, good luck on your web development adventure! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your body has a default margin of 8px, make is 0px.

```
body {
   margin:0px;
}
```

en get rid of the negative placements of elements you have now. Your #header will be as follows:

```
#header {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work as well. The header is still the same.

Comment: This is suppose to work - removing margin off body... also, your header css you need to specify the position because that top and left property wont do anything

Comment: Please check out https://jsbin.com/mohicizixe/edit?html,css,output, it should work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the #header like this?

```
#header {
/* top: -10px; */
left: -10px;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
padding-left: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work and the header is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Google</title>
<style>
body{
  margin:0;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;

}

a:hover {
    color: #222;
    background-color: #666666;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;

}

 #header {
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
 }

 #navbar {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;


 }

#me {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}



#footer {
    bottom: -150px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height: 30px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}



#terms {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -24px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

}


/*font color for the footer links */
.link:link, .link:visited {

    color: #777;
}


.link:hover {
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Google+</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Images</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Maps</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Play</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">YouTube</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gmail</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Drive</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="me">
        <li><a href="#">Nida Farooqui</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">0</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Share...</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0HkjOqmEXu8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/FQ22oIY4KjM/s24-c-mo/photo.jpg" width="24px" height="24px" alt="Nida Farooqui">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fez/512/FEZ-04-512.png" width="20px" height="20px">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="google-search">
    <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" id="logo">

    <form>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search Google or type URL" name="search" class="search">
    </form>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button>Google Search</button>
      <button id="lucky-button">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Advertising</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Business</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="terms">
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Privacy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Terms</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="link">Use Google.com</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Try add this into css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that already and have updated the link above. The navigation bar is still the same.

Comment: try to use universal reset: `* { margin:0;padding:0;}` + I have updated my answer with the code that worked for me (latest FF).

Answer (score 1):

I viewed your source and the page is still showing a margin of 8px for the body.  Try adding `!important` to the body margin in the css.  `!important` allows you to set a preference in the event there is clashing css.

```
body{margin:0 !important;}
```

Comment: That will at least set the body margin to 0 and allow you to work with the existing css.

Comment: You don't have a stylesheet linked in your header... Your styles are all being set by "User Agent Stylesheet".  Seems like the javascript is still pointing to Google.